# How to add HandWave library to android studio?

Tags: android

I am trying to add gesture detection capabilities to my application, and I found the following [library](https://github.com/kritts/HandWave). However, in its instructions, it says the following:

> I primarily use Eclipse for development therefore the instructions below are for Eclipse. I plan to add instructions for Android Studio later.
>   Clone the repo: git clone https://github.com/kritts/HandWave.git
>   Import TouchFreeLibrary as a library
>   Click File | Import | Android | Existing Android Code into Workspace
>   Select the TouchFreeLibrary project
>   Click Finish
>   Right-click on TouchFreeLibrary, then click Properties
>   In the project properties window, click the Android section
>   Check the Is Library checkbox
>   Add a reference to the TouchFreeLibrary project (click Remove to remove any broken references, then click Add to add the correct one)
>   You will also need to need to add OpenCV as a library. Detailed instructions on how to do so can be found here.
>   It's up to you which version of OpenCV you'd like to use (all of the recent versions should work just fine), but the 2.4.3 is the version I used during development.

However, I am not sure how this would work with Android Studio.

All answers are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of my previous answer (which by the way I apologize for not going into more depth) the original HandWave project has been forked and modified and can now be implemented within Android applications. It can now be imported into Android projects just as you would import any other library. Note, however, that you will also need to download OpenCV. Detailed instructions on how to do so can be found at [HandWave's repo](https://github.com/kritts/HandWave).

Answer (score 1):

There is now a version of HandWave that works on Android Studio. You will need to import OpenCV for Android as a library though, and change the OpenCV compile path in the Android Studio version of HandWave to the version of OpenCV that you imported. 
https://github.com/Manishearth/HandWave/tree/androidstudio